# gridview empty column and wrong order

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, gridview, extend

I have made one class and I have extend that class creating another class. I want to show all objects in GridView. I use second constructor, but why do i see also empty columns? I have never added nothing to age but it still shows up? How I can hide this properly way?
Is there anything bad in my code, what I can do better? And why nickName is first?

Website looks like this:

```
[nickName]           [name]       [age]
[MonkeyNickName1]    [Monkey1]    []
[MonkeyNickName2]    [Monkey2]    []
[MonkeyNickName3]    [Monkey3]    []
```

Class:

```
public class Monkey
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public Monkey(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Monkey(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
```

Another class:

```
public class ExtendMonkey : Monkey
{
    private string nickName;

    public ExtendMonkey(string name, string nickName) : base(name)
    {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public string NickName
    {
        get { return nickName; }
        set { nickName = value; }
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
List<ExtendMonkey> monkeyList = new List<ExtendMonkey>();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    monkeyList.Add(new ExtendMonkey("Monkey" + i, "MonkeyNickName" + i)
}


GridView1.DataSource = monkeyList;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Website:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Boundfield for each column you want to see and in the order you want to see them to avoid seeing the ones you don't want to see:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nickName" HeaderText="nickname">
    ...
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false; and then bind only the 
propetry you want to show in grid

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and this worked for me:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="nickName" HeaderText="Nick Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="age" HeaderText="Age" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
List<ExtendMonkey> monkeyList = new List<ExtendMonkey>();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
monkeyList.Add(new ExtendMonkey("Monkey" + i, "MonkeyNickName" + i));
}
GridView1.DataSource = monkeyList;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false; //this column has age
```

You can change the order of BoundFields to display as per your requirement. Also if you want to display age at any time you can simple change the *Visible* property of Column[2] from False to True.